# How to troubleshoot this Eclipse Git plugin installation?

Tags: eclipse, egit, jgit

The Eclipse Git plugin is installed on my Eclipse but I have no Git perspective and the Git features are not there, such as :

- Team history, comparison features are missing
- Repo icons on files, star icons on modified files are missing
- Git perspective and Git staging view are not there either

[image: Git plugin installation details]

[image: Git staging view missing]

[image: Git perspective missing]

EDIT:

- Eclipse version: 4.17.0.I20200902-1800
- JAVA version: jdk-11.0.8

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? Which version of Java is running it?

Comment: 4.17.0.I20200902-1800 jdk-11.0.8

Comment: Same with a fresh workspace? Why is your Eclipse so outdated and also EGit is not up to date?

Comment: This Eclipse comes from some master image. I have no idea why it's like this. Every Eclipse I ever downloaded had the git plugin pre-installed and working.